# S3 security policy seems to have no effect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to use S3 as maven repo. I created 2 IAM users for write and read, and used the Policy Generator to create the following bucket policy, which I added to the bucket.

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1442851625435",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1442851437396",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::closeup-maven/*",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::642063966117:user/maven-write"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1442851517972",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::closeup-maven/*",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::642063966117:user/maven-read"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1442851587864",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::closeup-maven",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::642063966117:user/maven-write",
                    "arn:aws:iam::642063966117:user/maven-read"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[anonymized]

When I run the Policy Simulator, I get denied for both users.

When I go to the bucket and set Everyone-access for everything, I still get denied in the Policy Simulator, when I am testing with these two users.

What am I missing?

Comment: What policy simulator settings are you using for action and resources?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a disclaimer in the IAM Policy Simulator that says it does not take into account policies attached to resources, like your bucket policy.  Maybe if you had the policy attached separately to the IAM users, the simulator would evaluate them.

> This action belongs to a service that supports access control mechanisms attached to resources.The policy simulator does not model these mechanisms, so results may differ in your production environment.

[image]